# Prove computation complexity by induction

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

Let say i have the following relation -

`T(1) = c1`

`T(n) = T(n/2) + n`

I need to prove by induction that this function is bounded by `O(n)`.
I just dont get how to choose `C,N_{0} > 0`.
If someone can show me the outline for those kind of proofs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit constant for proving that a complexity is `O(n)`. Coming back to the definition: `T(n)` is `O(n)` if `T(n) / n` is asymptotically *bounded*.

Now that suggests trying it as a first exploration, to see how it evolves:

```
T(n) / n = (T(n/2) + n) / n = T(n/2) / n + n / n
         = T(n/2) / n + 1
```

You can of course apply that again to `n/2`, `n/2/2` and so on. To simplify, let us assume that `n` is a power of 2: `n = 2^p`. We can then write:

```
T(2^p) / 2^p = T(2^(p-1)) / 2^p + 1
             = T(2^(p-2)) / ((2^p)*(2^(p-1))) + 1 / 2^p + 1
             = T(2^(p-3)) / ((2^p)*(2^(p-1))*(2^(p-2))) + 1 / (2^(p-1)*2^p) + 1/(2^p) + 1
             = ...
```

You can bring yourself back to `T(1)` this way (after `p` steps), but it should already be apparent that this is bounded: as the left side (`T(2^(p-k))`) gets gloser to `T(1)`, what is added to the *right* side is getting smaller and smaller at an exponential rate. In particular, we know that:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/(2*2) + 1/(2*2*2) + ...
```

Converges, so our sum of 1/(product of 2^something) should definitely behave. Let's formalise that intuition:

Let us see if we can find some `C` such that:

```
T(n) < n * C
```

It is true for `n==1`, as long as `C > c1`. Now, let us assume it's true for `n`, we have:

```
T(n*2) = T(n) + 2*n < n*C + n*2 = n*(C+2) = n*2 * (C+2)/2
```

So our relationship remains true through the recurrence as long as `(C + 2) / 2 <= C`. It is easy to show that this is true as long as `C >= 2`.

So if we take any `C > max(c1, 2)`, we have `T(1) < C`, and `T(n) < n*C` implies `T(2*n) < 2*n*C`, so we can conclude that:

```
T(n) < n * C for all p  (*)
```

Which implies that `T(n) ~ O(n)`, as `T(n) / n` is bounded by `C`.

There are other ways to proceed: expanding on the above exploration, you can express `T(2^p) / 2^p` as a series over `k<=p` and show that it converges. However, proofs by induction are usually the simplest way to handle recursive definitions.

---

`(*)`: Technically, we simply demonstrated it for all `n=2^p`, for all `p`. However, it is simple as well to prove by induction:

```
T(2) = T(1) + 1 > T(1)
T(n+1) = T((n+1)/2) + (n+1)
       = T(n/2) + n + 1     if n is even
       = T(n) + 1 
T(n+1) > T(n)               if n is even
T(n+1) = T((n+1)/2) + (n+1)
       = T(n/2 + 1) + (n+1) if n is odd
       > T(n/2) + n + 1
       > T(n) + 1
T(n+1) > T(n)               if n is odd
```

So `T(n)` is (strictly) increasing. Having `2^p < n < 2^(p+1)`, we have therefore:

```
T(n) / n < T(n) / 2^p < T(2^(p+1)) / 2^p = 2 * T(2^(p+1)) / 2^(p+1)
```

Since we know that `T(2^(p+1)) / 2^(p+1) < C` for all `p`, it follows immediately that `T(n) / n < 2 * C` for all `n`, and `T(n) ~ O(n)`